# Striped image in H264 stream

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, h.264, rtp

i'm working on a video streaming client in HTML, CSS, Javascript an plugin in Google Chrome.

The plugin creates an stream using RTP protocol and uses H264 codec to encode and decode the stream. But my receiving stream gets striped. How does this happen? and is there a fix fore it?

I tried different codecs, but this is not supported by the plugin in Chrome. It seams that H264 is the only one to get 2 way video.

I made a screenshot as an example.

[image]

Comment: THere is a ht/wt problem here. Video is fine. Somewhere some one is mentioning twice or 4 times the width of the video than it actually is. Nothing external here.

Comment: @av501 Could you elaborate? What do you mean by 'ht/wt' and 'Somewhere some one'? I'm working on this together with Patrick, and I'd like to add that the video is rotated 90 degrees. Do you suggest that fixing the rotation might fix the stripes as well?

Comment: height or width is given wrong somewhere in your chain. If you have a video of say width 240 but display it and tell your display that its width is 120 you'll see something like this. It could also be a potential wrong colorspace issue i.e. your display is expecting 4:2:2 but you gave 4:2:0 or something like that. That is what you need to look at. If you have seen something like this before you'll recognize it easily. So somewhere width / stride is wrong or colorspace given is wrong which is why the display is coming up like that. (Most probably between decode and display there is an error).